# Firefox Flash player fails to load swf through localhost

Tags: flash, macos, firefox, operating-system, localhost

**Hardware/Browser/plugin**

- Mac OS X v10.7.2 (Lion), 64bit
- Firefox v9.0.1
- "Shockwave Flash 11.1.102.55" debug edition.

**Development tools**

- Flash Builder 4.5
- Tomcat v7.0.23

**Setup**

- Flex application (a swf in itself) loads swf files and is used to markup swf document content.
- crossdomain.xml set to allow all and can be seen when you type
  localhost:3000/crossdomain.xml in the Firefox browser.
- Used "Global Security Settings panel" to "Always allow" all relevant directories.
  http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

**Observations**

- Flex app loads in Safari Flash and Chrome Flash
  (through a local html file or through localhost server).
- Flex app loads in Firefox from a local html file,
  but fails to load if loaded as a localhost:3000 served file.
- tail -f ~/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash Player/Logs/policyfiles.txt shows
  OK: Root-Level SWF loaded http://localhost:3000/FlexApp.swf

**Code Snippet (from HTML file)**

```
<object id="_773595058" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="../FlexApp.swf" name="_773595058">
<param value="always" name="allowscriptaccess">
<param value="SwfFile='/swfs/doc.swf'" name="flashvars">
</object>
```

**crossdomain.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

I'm stumped on this, anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: There isn't a space between height and type attributes in your code snippet. Not sure if that would matter. Have you looked at it through Firebug's Network tag? Is it loading it at all, getting refused, not found, etc.? Have you tried using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: Hey lewiguez, The space was a typing mistake in entering this problem :)  Firebug Net Flash shows the swf got loaded 483 kbytes.

Comment: Tried to load Firefox in safe mode but made no difference.  Only Firefox fails to load the swf for it to display.